# Remove a Layer from an AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Is there a way (using either the AWS CLI or some API) to programmatically *remove* a layer from an AWS lambda function?

That is, I know I can add or update a layer version by running something like the following

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function-name --layer arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:000000000:layer:layer-name:7
```

However, this only allows me to add or update the function's configuration.  I'd like to programmatically *remove* the `arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:000000000:layer:layer-name:7` layer from the AWS function named `my-function-name`

Comment: `aws lambda update-function-configuration` doesn't take a single layer. There is no `--layer` argument, only a `--layers` argument that takes the full list of layers for the function. If you call this without listing the layer you want to remove, it should remove it.

Comment: Just call it `aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function-name --layers`

Comment: Ah, thank you both. An empty `--layers` option did it.  Also, FWIW, the version of the AWS CLI command I have appears to alias the option `--layer` to `--layers`.  Happy to accept a version of the above as the best answer if someone wants to make it an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

The values passed to `--layers` (note: not `--layer`, which appears to be an alias to the actual option) option *replaces* your entire layers configuration. This means that, by passing an empty `--layers`

```
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function-name --layers
```

you can remove your entire layers configuration.